# csrf token invalid when user's session times out

Tags: session, csrf, cherrypy

Used this flask example for implementing a csrf token in my cherrypy app for all my site's forms...

[flask csrf token example](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/3/)

However when a user's session times out the csrf token in session becomes None.

```
token = cherrypy.session.get('csrf_token')
if token is None or token != cherrypy.request.params['csrf_token']:
    raise cherrypy.HTTPError(403)
```

How can I work around this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not need to work around this, as the behaviour you are describing is correct. If the csrf token persists for a long time, it is not very useful - the whole idea is that it is not reusable, at least not over a long period of time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.   I wondered how amazon handled timeouts when filling out their registration page.  They seem to redirect back to the registration page and they keep all user content except passwords.  That seems like a more user friendly alternative to the 403 Error and would still be secure - does that sound correct?